# Trigger to Create Event Record is Not Firing Properly

Tags: trigger, custom-object, event

I'm a new developer and would really appreciate some help on a trigger that I created that is not firing properly.

**Purpose of Trigger:** I use Einstein Activity Capture (EAC) to sync my Google calendar's events with my Dev Org. When Google sends the event to my Salesforce Dev Org, my trigger detects it and fires. The purpose of the trigger is to create a new Task_Custom__c (custom object) record every time an Event (standard object) record is created.

**Problem**: The Task_Custom__c record is supposed to pull in all values from the Event record. The problem is that the Event time is not getting populated on the Task_Custom__c record UNLESS the original event (in Google) is updated. So, when the original Google event is created in Salesforce, the Event record has the time but does not copy it to the Task_Custom__c record. When I update the event in Google, the updated Event in Salesforce ONLY THEN creates a new Task_Custom__c record with the time value.

I suspect that my trigger events aren't written correctly but I'm not sure. I've spent hours on this and would love some help. Thank you!

```
trigger create_Task_on_Event on Event (before insert, before update) 
{
    //Create list for new Task Item records to enable DML operation outside of for-loop
    List<Task_Custom__c> newTasks = new List<Task_Custom__c>();
    
    //Trigger for Event object ()
    for (Event calendarEvent : Trigger.new)
    {
        //Set default values for fields on new Event records
        calendarEvent.IsReminderSet = TRUE;
        
        //Declare variables for Event Date/Time fields
        DateTime startTime = calendarEvent.StartDateTime; 
        DateTime endTime = calendarEvent.EndDateTime; 
        
        //Create new Task record when Event record is created
        Task_Custom__c newTask = new Task_Custom__c ();
        newTask.Task_Month__c = 'a016g00000Kdz33AAB';
        newTask.Task_Week__c = 'a0C6g000001y6RyEAI';
        
        if(calendarEvent.StartDateTime != Null)
        {
        //Extract Time from Event Date/Time field
        //Assign to Time field on Task record
        newTask.Start_Time_Current__c = 
        Time.newInstance(
        startTime.hour(), 
        startTime.minute(), 
        startTime.second(), 
        startTime.millisecond());           
        }

        if(calendarEvent.EndDateTime != Null)
        {
        newTask.End_Time_Current__c = 
        Time.newInstance(
        endTime.hour(), 
        endTime.minute(), 
        endTime.second(), 
        endTime.millisecond()); 
        }
        
        //Set required Task field values    
        newTask.Subject__c = calendarEvent.Subject;
        newTask.Task_Description__c = calendarEvent.Description;
        
        //Assign events from Google calendar to the Backlog Category
        if(calendarEvent.location != 'Monday' && calendarEvent.location != 'Tuesday' 
           && calendarEvent.location != 'Wednesday' && calendarEvent.location != 'Thursday'
           && calendarEvent.location !='Friday' && calendarEvent.location != 'Saturday' 
           && calendarEvent.location !='Sunday')
        {
          newTask.Task_Category__c = 'Backlog: Unique';
        }
        Else
        {
          newTask.Task_Category__c = calendarEvent.location;            
        }

        newTasks.add(newTask);
        system.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG);
        system.debug(newTask.Start_Time_Current__c);
        system.debug(newTask.End_Time_Current__c);
    }
    insert newTasks;
}
```

Comment: the first note is that you create a new `Task_Custom__c` each time event is updated, which is guess suboptimal

Comment: regarding your question. You say that when you create Event in SFDC it has Start Time, are you sure that this is StartDateTime?

Comment: One thing that might help is to leave `calendarEvent.IsReminderSet = TRUE;` is before and move all other logic into `after insert`, `after update`, because you don't do any other modifications on original Event and maybe for some reason this dateTime is not populated

Comment: Yes, my preference would be to update the already existing Task_Custom__c record however, I do not know how to do so.

Comment: Yes, I am using StartDateTime, per the code above.

Comment: I will try splitting this into two triggers (Before, After) as you mention.